# How to determine whether a solid has dissolved or no reaction occurred?

Tags: solutions, precipitation

From this link: https://chemhaven.org/che111/lab/Lab_9_Unknown_Anion_F21.pdf

> When dissolving a solid or precipitate,
> only a portion is dissolved, thus leaving some behind, and fooling a student into incorrectly reporting that no reaction occurred,
> or that a precipitate formed. This can be avoided by realizing that the original compounds are generally crystalline, and will
> sit at the bottom of a test tube (or settle out quickly), while a precipitate will have a milky appearance, and tend to spread
> evenly throughout the solution.

I am finding it difficult to understand what this quote means. Let's say I dissolve a solid in a reagent. How am I supposed to tell whether (a) a solid dissolved partially, (b) no reaction occurred, and (c) a precipitate has formed?

Comment: I would take it as a warning. Moreover a test involves tiny amount of solid. It basically means wait enough, shake the tube, look carefully. Of course there can be plenty of reactions happening with undetectable signs, in a test tube. It also depends on what liquid is in the tube and what one might expect. Ps the link isn't that useful, as such.

Answer (score 1):

> How am I supposed to tell whether (a) a solid dissolved partially, (b)
> no reaction occurred, and (c) a precipitate has formed?

With your two eyes as the detector for (a) and (c). For (b) you use your intution/brain and previous chemistry knowledge.

The quote is basically advising that one should be very careful during scientific observations.*

(a) If a solid has dissolved partially, you will *see* a reduction in the amount of the solid. Practice this instruction by slowly stirring a tablespoon of sugar or salt in half glass of water and see how the amount of solid decreases slowly as you stir.

(b) Nobody can guess beforehand if it is a completely new and an unknown reaction. However, you know what you are adding beforehand and what is present in the test tube. So, this instruction asks you to brainstorm if there is no color change, ppt. formation etc and ask youself: Is a reaction expected in this scenario?

(c) Again use your eyes.

---

- Several major discoveries have been made by good visual observations. The field of complexometric titration was invented by observing that when Eriochrome (dye) solution is discarded in the sink and tap water is opened to wash the dye, the dye changed its color to blue from wine red. What caused the color change? He thought. Calcium and magnesium ions water...this led Schwarzenbach to open a new area of research which is still useful today.